# How should I pass values into JPQL query?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I'm working on test, that will check if object had been saved into database. Test will save object with unique values and after that I want to fetch this object from database and check if it is not null. Id is auto generated, so I need to find this object by name.

My test looks like this:

```
@Test
public void shouldAddNewEmployee(){

    String firstNameTest = "Jon";
    String lastNameTest = "Doe";
    double salary1test = 10.0;
    String salary2test = "10.00";
    String localityTest = "LosAngeles";
    String zipCodeTest = "00-000";
    String streetTest = "LosAngeles str.";
    int streetNumberTest = 10;

    Employee testEmployee = new Employee(
            firstNameTest,
            lastNameTest,
            salary1test,
            salary2test,
            localityTest,
            zipCodeTest,
            streetTest,
            streetNumberTest);

    EmployeeRepository.addNewEmployeeFromCLI(testEmployee);

    String customQueryFindJonDoe = "select e from Employee e where e.firstName = Jon and e.lastName = Doe";
    EntityManager entityManager = JPAUtils.openEntityManager();

    List<Employee> foundJonDoe = entityManager.createQuery(customQueryFindJonDoe).getResultList();

    Assertions.assertNotEquals(null, foundJonDoe);

    if (entityManager.isOpen()) {
        entityManager.close();
    }


}
```

after running it I get error:

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'Jon' in 'where clause'

How should this query look like?

Comment: You should quote params with `' '`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the parameters on the query:

```
String customQueryFindJonDoe = 
       "select e from Employee e where e.firstName = :firstname and e.lastName = :lastName";
EntityManager entityManager = JPAUtils.openEntityManager();

TypedQuery<Employee> q = entityManager.createQuery(customQueryFindJonDoe, Employee.class);
q.setParameter("firstname", "Jon");
q.setParameter("lastName", "Doe");

List<Employee> foundJonDoe = q.getResultList();
```

More about querying you can find here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-querylanguage002.htm#BNBRG
https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query

Or you buy a book
https://www.apress.com/de/book/9781484234198

Comment: Test passed! THX! could you also please tell me how can I assign this found object to single variable instead of collection? It is not a bog deal, but just wondering - if I'm looking for one particular entity, than what's the point in adding it to list, plus it would be easier to delete this object from database, since it had only been created in purpose of test.

Comment: call getSingleResult() instead of getResultList(). You should definitely learn JPA before doing further development.